# lost profile access to 3 separate computers the same day. computers just lock up

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have three dell computers with Windows 7 professional on the Server using Windows Server 2003.
On 9/11 those three computers which were installed on the system in my office all froze up.  When you try to reset them they get to the Windows screen and the curser just goes round and round.  In safe mode the user and password boxes come on and we can get in but no access to the server or internet.
We have tried to delete the profile and set up a new one to get the computer to allow us to sign in under a different domain and it seemed to work but then shortly it went back to the same problem.  Two other computers and 2 laptops on the same server are not affected at all in the same office.  Any ideas.

Comment: What antivirus program do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a virus on these machines. It was just waiting until 9/11 to act.

I have heard of viruses that wait until certain days. Then crash or empty the C drive.